# EF Core - Inherited DBContext Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to setup the following using EF Core and struggling to see how to manage migrations cleanly without having them duplicated in derived DBContext assembly projects

[image]

The DbContext contains all of my base entities as DBSet and I have multiple Customer specific DbContexts, of which inherit from DbContext so they can access the underlying entity datasets, plus entities of their own - and some extended tables based on the DbContext model (Think custom tables with new customer specific columns which are attached to the main table using EFs discriminator functionality).

**Migrations Creation Issue**

I am struggling to see how I can keep the Migrations creation clean for this setup and I am having to duplicate migrations into all Customer DB context assemblies after creating, for example, a new migration adding a new entity/table/dbset to DbContext - I have to create a specific migration for each [Customer].DbContext I have which is getting to be an overhead and error prone.

Is there a way to create Migrations in the [Customer].DbContext assemblies *only* and have them be aware of what to create from a base DbContext perspective as well as the 'additions' from the specific customer DbContext in a safe manner?

I am trying to avoid having to create Migrations in both the DbContext and then also in every Customer DbContext project because the DbContext is changed with far more frequency than the Customer DbContexts.

I think the answer may be in only ever creating migrations in the [Customer].DbContext projects but that also feels like overhead every time something changes in the DbContext itself.

The other option I wondered, but couldn't see if it was correct - is it possible to apply two sets of Migrations as part of the deployment process whilst keeping them in sync?

**Apply DbContext Migration**
**Apply Customer[n] DbContext Migration**

I couldn't figure out how to keep the Migration creation distinct because every time I create a Migration for Customer[n].DbContext - as it inherits from the DbContext, it will always try to create migrations to create the DbContext entities even though they were already there (because they were applied by the main DbContext Migration already).

Is there an established way of achieving this kind of pattern? It felt like it would be something reasonably common, but maybe not!

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Alternating between multiple models with the same DbContext type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/dynamic-model) - maybe this will help you. Use one DbContext with different models instead of two different contexts.